# Writing to ADLS from Synapse Notebook with account key

Tags: python, azure, pyspark, azure-synapse, azure-data-lake-gen2

I am trying to write a file from an Azure Synapse Notebook to ADLS Gen2 while authenticating with the account key.

When I use python and the `DataLakeServiceClient`, I can authenticate via key and write a file without a problem. If I try to authenticate with the same key for Spark, I get `java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: Operation failed: "This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.", 403, PUT,`.

With **PySpark and authorization with the account key** [NOT WORKING]:

```
myaccountname = ""
account_key = ""
spark.conf.set(f"fs.azure.account.key.{myaccountname}.dfs.core.windows.net", account_key)

dest_container = "container_name"
dest_storage_name = "storage_name"
destination_storage = f"abfss://{dest_container }@{dest_storage_name }.dfs.core.windows.net"

df.write.mode("append").parquet(destination_storage + "/raw/myfile.parquet")
```

But I can write a file with Python and the `DataLakeServiceClient` and **also authorization with the account key** [WORKING]:

```
from azure.storage.filedatalake import DataLakeServiceClient

# DAP ADLS configurations
storage_name = ""
account_key = ""
container_name = ""

service_client = DataLakeServiceClient(account_url=f"https://{storage_name}.dfs.core.windows.net", credential=account_key)
file_system_client = service_client.get_file_system_client(container_name)

dir_client = file_system_client.get_directory_client(directory_name)
dir_client.create_directory()
file_client = dir_client.get_file_client(file_name)
file_client.create_file()
file_client.append_data(file_content, offset=0, length=len(file_content))
file_client.flush_data(len(file_content))
```

What am I doing wrong? I was under the impression using `spark.conf.set` for a URL-key is enough?

Comment: have you setup a database scoped credential ?

Comment: assuming you have the **Storage Blob Data Contributor role** on the storage account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it by using a **LinkedService**. In the LinkedService I used the AccountKey (retrieved from a KeyVault).

For some the direct reason the authentication with the account key in the code did not work in the Synapse Notebook, despite the User having all required permissions.

**UPDATE**: According to Microsoft's third level tech support, authentication with an account key from within Synapse is not possible (!!!) You *HAVE* to use their LinkedServices.

If anyone else needs to authenticate:

```
linkedServiceName_var = "my_linked_service_name"
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.auth.type", "SAS")
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.sas.token.provider.type", "com.microsoft.azure.synapse.tokenlibrary.LinkedServiceBasedSASProvider")
spark.conf.set("spark.storage.synapse.linkedServiceName", linkedServiceName_var)

raw_container_name = "my_container"
raw_storageaccount_name = "my_storage_account"
CONNECTION_STR = f"abfs://{raw_container_name}@{raw_storageaccount_name}.dfs.core.windows.net"


my_df = spark.read.parquet(CONNECTION_STR+ "/" + filepath)
```

Answer (score -1):

### --Update

Can you double check if you or the user running this has ADLSGen2 access and right permissions (`contributer role on subscription` or `Storage Blob Data Owner at the storage account level` or `Blob Storage Contributor Role to the service principal in the scope of the Data Lake Storage Gen2 storage account.` ) depending on your setup.

Make sure you have the **valid account key** copied from the Azure portal.

Just in case....

> To enable other users to use the storage account after you create your
> workspace, you will have to perform below tasks:
>
> - Assign other users to the Contributor role on workspace
> - Assign other users to a Workspace, SQL, or Spark admin role using Synapse Studio
> - Assign yourself and other users to the  **Storage Blob Data Contributor**  role on the storage account

Also, if you are using MSI for synapse workspace, make sure the you as a user have same permission level in the notebook.

---

Going through the official MS docs on [Azure Synapse connecting to Azure storage account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/azure/synapse-analytics#azure-synapse-to-azure-storage-account)

> In case you have set up an **account key** and secret for the storage
> account, you can set `forwardSparkAzureStorageCredentials` to `true`,
> in which case Azure Synapse connector automatically discovers the
> account access key set in the notebook session configuration or the
> global Hadoop configuration and forwards the storage account access
> key to the connected Azure Synapse instance by creating a temporary
> Azure [database scoped
> credential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-database-scoped-credential-transact-sql).

Just add this option while `df.write`

```
.option("forwardSparkAzureStorageCredentials", "true")
```

Comment: I added the option  to the `write`, but I still receive the same error - even though I use the same account key in both approaches. I got the `Contributor` role with full access to all resources and read/writes work when I access the storage via Python.  Im confused to say the least :D

Comment: I just looked into the logs of the storage account and there it said that spark tried to write with "AuthenticatenType" `OAuth` and not with the key. For other requests I have the AuthenticatenType `AccountKey`...

Comment: please check edited

Comment: just as an afterthought because I still struggle to solve it with an account key: I have Contributor role on the entire Subscription, the ADLS and Synapse. Still cannot get it to work, neither with read nor with writes.

Comment: But this shouldnt matter?? Why should I need contributor role if I have the account key? That makes no sense